# Transformation of web.config on spring objects

Tags: c#, spring, asp.net-mvc-4, web.config-transform

I'm trying to transform part of my web.config:

```
<spring>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
        <object name="MyPresenter" type="MyRepositoryStub, MyNameSpace" />
    </objects>
</spring>
```

I'm trying to transform it like this:

```
<spring>
  <objects>
    <object name="MyPresenter"
            type="MyRepository, MyNameSpace"
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
            xdt:Location="Match(name)" />
  </objects>
</spring>
```

Clearly I'm missing something since It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself:

In my webconfig I have:

```
 <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
```

But in my transform I have:

```
<objects>
```

without xmlns